# why echo ? is returning a single | character to the stdout

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

I am trying to understand the output of this command- `echo ?`.
The output I see is a single `|` charcter.

Comment: What is the output of `echo ?` in your system??

Comment: I edited my quetsion and changed  my command `echo abc?` to simply `echo ?`

Comment: @RaviKumar: The behavior is still the same. It would still return a file/directory with a single character name. Try `echo ??` for 2 length file names

Comment: If you do not want this to happen and do not want to turn off globbing, quote the `?`, as in `echo '?'` or `echo \?`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `?` is a special wildcard character for the shell. $abc is not present, so it's expanded to an empty string, and `?` is replaced by any one-character file or directory existing in the current directory. So, there probably is a file/directory named `|` in your current directory.

On my system, the output is different:

```
$ echo $abc?
_ 1
```

If there's no one-character file/directory, the `?` comes out unexpanded.

And, indeed, there are directories `_` and `1`.

Comment: Mine returns `~`!

Comment: I'm getting `?` only. Or any other special character following `$abc` is the output.

Comment: @AbhikBose: So, there's no one-character file/directory.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen then you have a file/dir called `~` in your home. As choroba explained, `echo ?` basically means "print the list of filenames in the current directory that match the glob `?`". The glob `?` matches any single character, so that's what's printed.

Comment: Instead I have vims backup files like `apples.txt~`

Comment: Ok I see a `~` folder owned by root! Strange things happen!

Comment: @choroba you are correct!  When I do `ls \|` , i do see a file named as `|`. Looks like bash will match the first file with a single charcter based on the sort order. so output other see could be different. I do not know what the `|` is for in my system.

Comment: After I removed the file `|` from my home directory, when I do `echo ?` it does return just the `?` as expected. When bash does not find a match for the wildcard it will just return the wildcard.

Comment: I guess you created it with `... > | ...` when wrongly combining redirection with pipe (I often find files named `|` or `{` all over the place).

Comment: On zsh in case of no one character filename the output is `zsh: no matches found: ?`.

Comment: @jimmij: You can get similar behaviour in bash with `shopt -s failglob`.

Comment: yes, sure, and can get rid of any output with `shopt -s nullglob`/`setopt nullglob`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the ? is split into a word and it contains a glob character (`?`) that basically says:

> Print the list of filenames in the current directory that match the glob `?`.

The glob `?` match any file with a single character. So, this works:

```
$ touch a \| b
$ echo ?
| a b
$ ls -l ?
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Dec 29 10:03 '|'
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Dec 29 10:03  a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Dec 29 10:03  b
```

If there is no file/directory with one character, this happens:

```
$ rm a \| b
…
$ echo ?
?
```

That is the output in bash with default settings.
To clearly see the files do:

```
$ ls -l ?
ls: cannot access '?': No such file or directory
```

If `nullglob` is activated, no output will be printed

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ echo ?
$
```